# How to read value from 3D Print Analysis Report and use it in a script

Tags: scripting, faces, 3d-printing, smooth

is there a way to get the value from one of the 3D Print Toolkit report items and use it in a script? I have only a superficial understanding of python and using it for scripting in Blender. When I right click on the item I wish to use and select edit source the 3D Print Analysis python script is opened up in Blender's text editor. Line 64 is highlighted and its contents are the following:`col.operator("mesh.print3d_select_report", text=text, icon=self._type_to_icon[bm_type],).index = i`
The data I wish to use is the Intersecting Faces data. Blender's python tooltips says that data is index=2. Where is this data stored? Is it in the `mesh.print3d_select_report`? Is there a way to access it? My goal with this is to store it in a temporary variable that will be used in a conditional statement so that I can write a simple script. For example, check if that value is not zero then select those interesting faces, grow the selection and execute a simple operation like vertices smooth. After running vertices smooth run the 3D Print Check All command once again and check if that value is not zero again until, hopefully, vertices smoothing removes all intersecting faces. I think this automating can help me with some of my workflow. Thank you for the help attached is an image of the 3D Print Toolkit item data I want to use.
[image]

Comment: Looking at the add-on code, it appears the report results are not saved in an accessible way, nor stored in custom properties. Can't find a way to directly access the label objects of a drawn UI panel, but this seems like the only way. You can modify the add-on code to spew out the results into anything you'd like though.